# Unity PC (Windows) Build failing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I am able to build other projects correctly, so this is not a problem with my Visual Studio Installation as one of the errors suggest.

I can play the game in the unity editor.

I was able to build this project today morning.

This happened after installing unity beta package "Animation rigging".

I have tried:

1. Clicking on Assets => Re import all
2. Restarting unity
3. Building to a completely different location

I also saw someone who was able to fix his problem with deleting the plugins folder, but I don't have a folder called plugins in my project.

Here are the error messages

1)

> Warning Unable to find player assembly: C:\Users\PC\CODE\ProjectCorruption\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object) Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl(BuildReport) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:166) Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs(BuildReport) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:46) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

2. 

> ErrorBuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.1.1) failed running stdout: Burst requires Visual Studio (installable via Add Component in the Unity Installer) or the C++ build tools for Visual Studio, along with the Windows 10 SDK in order to build a standalone player for Windows with X86_SSE4 Unable to determine tools version of MSVC Linker, please ensure you have visual studio installed correctly! stderr:
> Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:663) Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:601) Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:575) Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:290) Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:46) UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at :0) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

3. 

> Error Error building Player: BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.1.1) failed running
> stdout: Burst requires Visual Studio (installable via Add Component in the Unity Installer) or the C++ build tools for Visual Studio, along with the Windows 10 SDK in order to build a standalone player for Windows with X86_SSE4 Unable to determine tools version of MSVC Linker, please ensure you have visual studio installed correctly! stderr:

4. 

> Error d3d12: generating mipmaps for array textures is not yet supported.

5. 

> Error Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 17 seconds (17368 ms) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) 6) Error UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bb] in :0 at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

HDRP Unity version 2019.4.10f1 Building a PC (Windows) build from a Windows 10 1909 (My PC) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error messages, and going off what you say you have tried I would try clearing Visual Studio off of your machine it seems to be failing to compile your code, give that a try.

Comment: I did try that, I updated Visual studio, then reinstalled Visual Studio, the thing is, that unity compiles other PC Projects, This happened after I added unity package "Animation rigging"

Comment: Visual Studio (installable via Add Component in the Unity Installer) - This is one of your error messages perhaps you are missing a module in visual studio after a new installation. Visual studio Installer > Modify > Game Development (Enable and install) OR you could try Unity Hub > Installs > (Your current install) > Three dots > Add modules and then install VScode